# Argoworkflow can't call template inputs parameters within steps

Tags: argo-workflows

```
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: small-
spec:
  entrypoint: fan-out-in-params-workflow
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: jira-ticket
        value: INFRA-000
  templates:

  - name: fan-out-in-params-workflow
    steps:
    - - name: generate
        template: gen-host-list
    - - name: pre-conditions
        template: pre-conditions
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: host
            value: "{{item}}"
        withParam: "{{steps.generate.outputs.result}}"
  - name: gen-host-list
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: host
        path: /tmp/host.txt
        s3:
          key: host.txt
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        filename="{{ inputs.artifacts.host.path }}"
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            json.dump([line.rstrip() for line in f], sys.stdout)
  - name: pre-conditions
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: host
    steps:
    - - name: online-check
        template: online-check
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: host
            value: {{inputs.parameters.host}}
  - name: online-check
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: host
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command:
        - python
      source: |
        print({{inputs.parameters.host}})
```

Hi there, I'm quite new to argoworkflow. Now I'm trying to call the template pre-conditions inputs parameters host like I posted above. But it seems the host params passes to template pre-conditions successfully but I can't get it in steps online-check, anyone can give me some advice ? Anything will be appreciated !